# Swift 4 Argument passed to call that takes no arguments

Tags: swift, error-handling, closures

I tried to do error handling via `throw completion handler`.
When i call completion i get compiler error "**Argument passed to call that takes no arguments**". How can i fix my code?

```
private func executeRefreshTokenRequest(_ completion: @escaping () throws -> Void) {

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).sync {
      guard let refreshToken = currentRefreshToken else {
        completion({ throw RefreshTokenError.notFounded }) 
      // Argument passed to call that takes no arguments
      }
    var refreshTokenUrlRequest:CustomURLRequest
    do {
      refreshTokenUrlRequest = try AuthService.refresh(token: refreshToken).doUrlRequest()
    } catch (let error) {
      completion({ throw UrlRequest.notDone }) 
    // Argument passed to call that takes no arguments
    }
      execute(refreshTokenUrlRequest, PlaceToken.self) { [weak self] (placeToken, error) in
        if error != nil {
          self?.cancelAllRequests()
          NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("AuthorizationFail"), object: nil)
        } else {

          Cache.currentAuthToken = placeToken
        }
        completion()
      }
  }
```

Comment: you should pass the error as parameter of your closure, not throw it

Comment: Q = error message since that is the central issue.
Also, tagged as a closures issue since the root problem is the method's treatment of errors in the closure.